error adding /managed-agents/serviceconnect to fsnotify watcher, error: no such file or directory
Title: Error Deploying Docker Image to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: /managed-agents/serviceconnect Directory Not Found
Body:
I am trying to deploy a Docker image created using Jib on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but the deployment is failing with the following error:
error adding /managed-agents/serviceconnect to fsnotify watcher, error: no such file or directory
What I've Tried:
I verified that the directory /managed-agents/serviceconnect does not exist in my Docker image.
I terminated the existing Elastic Beanstalk environment and created a new one, but I still encounter the same error.
I checked the Elastic Beanstalk logs for any additional clues but couldn't find anything helpful.
My Current Setup:
I am deploying a single-container application using Docker.
My Dockerrun.aws.json file is configured, but I suspect there might be some issue related to ECS Service Connect.
